# Why Am I Getting A Type Error When Running This Function?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to create a function where it returns a list of all values in the dictionary that are also keys. However I keep getting 'TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable' printed in the Terminal. Why is this code not working?

```
def values_that_are_keys(my_dictionary):
 for element, numbers in my_dictionary.items():
  if numbers in element:
      print(numbers)

values_that_are_keys({1:100, 2:1, 3:4, 4:10})
```

Comment: Because `element` is an integer. You can't check if something is _in_ an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `element` is an integer. You can't check if something is *in* an integer.

If you want to check if `numbers` (which, incidentally, should not be a plural) is a key in `my_dictionary`, you want

```
if numbers in my_dictionary:
    ...
```

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping:

> **key in d**
>
> Return True if *d* has a key *key*, else False.

Comment: But won’t this code check if ‘numbers’ is in both the key AND value of the dictionary?

Comment: @t92 No, it won't. It will check if it is a key. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping